# How to Constraint to Margin end?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I want to add an `arrow icon` to `end` of `LinearLayout`:

[image: Desired Layout]

**What is the best way to accomplish this?**

I succeed by wrapping the `LinearLayout` and `ImageView` with `ConstraintLayout`, but it feels that there is a more elegant way than using `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"`.

On first attempt the `ImageView` was part of the `LinerLayout` (without the `ConstraintLayout`), is there is a way to get the desired layout from here?

[image: First Attempt]

Current `.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_constraint_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_16sdp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:id="@+id/profile_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_48dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/nav_bottom_sheet_profile_description" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_4sdp">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/jesta_profile_full_name_default"/>

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/jesta_profile_phone_number_default"/>
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/jesta_profile_edit_profile_icon_description"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profile_layout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

...
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constrain your arrow icon only for the `top`, `bottom` and `end`, it will automatically affix itself in the very end of your layout

so instead of this:

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/jesta_profile_edit_profile_icon_description"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profile_layout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"/>
```

have this:

```
    <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
                android:contentDescription="@string/jesta_profile_edit_profile_icon_description"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                />
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped, please consider accepting as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: yep it needs 3 min to pass

Comment: I forgot about that!